# Creating a loading sequence of an application

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babel.js

I am using Webpack to create a sort of loading sequence of the application. I can simply call `prepareInfosite().render()` and I don't need to care about the hidden async nature of it.

```
export function prepareInfosite() {
    return setupRenderer((resolve) => {
        require.ensure(['./infosite'], (require) => resolve(require('./infosite')), 'infosite');
    });
}

export function prepareLoading() {...}
export function prepareGame() {...}

const uiContainerElement = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(uiContainerElement);

function setupRenderer(resolver) {
    let uiModule = null;
    let rendered = false;
    const renderArgs = [uiContainerElement];

    function executeRender() {
        if (rendered === true && uiModule !== null) {
            uiModule.render(...renderArgs);
        }
    }

    resolver((resolvedUiModule) => {
        uiModule = resolvedUiModule;
        executeRender();
    });

    return {
        render(...args) {
            rendered = true;
            renderArgs.push(...args);
            executeRender();
        },
    };
}
```

Originally, the `setupRenderer` looked like this, but since I am using Babel, it has polyfilled the Promise and size has grown from like 6kB to 22kB (after uglify2!), which isn't very nice.

```
function setupRenderer(resolver) {
    const promise = new Promise(resolver);
    return {
        render(...args) {
            promise.then((uiModule) => uiModule.render(uiContainerElement, ...args));
        },
    };
}
```

Do you think there is a nicer way how to express this without any external dependency?

Additionally, I would like to DRY up the lines with `require.ensure`. I am not entirely sure how this works, but is there some way how to specify name of loaded file dynamically, perhaps using context?

Comment: Just as an FYI, we encountered something similar in work... you can "specify the name of the loaded file dynamically", but all files must be known ahead of time. You can use `require.context` for this, but you wouldn't be able to load just *any* file, only files that are available at compile-time.

Comment: Yes it's perfectly fine with me, my set of files is well known, I just would like to extract that `require.ensure`call to a function and call that with name of file. Can you please post an example on how that can be done with context? I am quite lost in that thing yet.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you think there is a nicer way how to express this without any external dependency?

Use [Babel preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env/) to only include browsers from the last two years. In that case, the [promise polyfill is not needed](https://caniuse.com/promises). For example

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["since 2016"]
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

> Additionally, I would like to DRY up the lines with require.ensure. I am not entirely sure how this works, but is there some way how to specify name of loaded file dynamically, perhaps using context?

Use a wrapper function to pass the strings as arguments:

```
return setupRenderer((resolve) => { ensurance('./infosite', 'infosite')});
```

And define the function before the call:

```
function ensurance(path, name){
  require.ensure([path], (require) => resolve(require(path)), name);
}
```

**References**

- [Babel: env preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env/)
- [caniuse: promises](https://caniuse.com/promises)